# Setting Button command javafx

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I've been using JFrame to learn graphics and test my code because I know it much better.  Now I want to update to Javafx.  I have this JListener class that handles all the buttons for my JFrame.  Is it possible to still use this class with Javafx? If so how?

For example, with JFrame I could use Button.setActionCommand("command"); and when the button was pressed it would run this with the actionListener, can I do this same thing with javafx?

```
package src.com.Kingdom;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.*;

public class JListener implements ActionListener
 {

private boolean registered = false;
registerClient register;
loginClient login;
static GUIs gui = new GUIs(); 



@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    switch(e.getActionCommand()) {

        case("login"):
            login = new loginClient(gui.getUsername(), gui.getPassword());
            System.out.println("Login");
            break;
        case("exit"):
            System.out.println("exit");
            break;
        case("register"):
            System.out.println("register");
            gui.getFrame().dispose();
            gui.createRegisterGui();
            break;
        case("registerperson"):
            if(gui.checkRegister()) {
            if(hasInternet()) {
                if(!(registered)) {
                    registered = true;
                    try {
                        register =
                                new registerClient(gui.getUsername(), gui.getPassword(), gui.getEmail(), gui.getAge());
                    } catch(Exception ex) {
                        GUIs.showError(ex.getMessage());
                    }
                    if(!(register.isRegistered())) {
                    gui.createLoginGui();
                }
                    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        public void run() {
                            registered = false;
                        }
                    },1000*1);
                } 
            } else {
                GUIs.showError("No Internet!  Please connect to internet to connect!");
            }
            } else {

                GUIs.showError("Problem with registration format");
             }
            break;

    }

}
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with JavaFX. However, if I was inclined to learn, I would read its documentation to find out how it implements event handling. I expect that much of your code will still be useful, just not the exact interface and method names.

Comment: Swing and JavaFX are two separate toolkits. You cannot use the same listeners for both (though the principals are very similar). Read the documentation and tutorials to learn a new toolkit, e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/button.htm#JFXUI141

Comment: If you are using `JavaFX` nodes, you need to change your imports to be `JavaFx` imports, not `awt`.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Not true. There is no such thing as an "action command" in JavaFX.

Comment: This style, FWIW, is not particularly good practice. In particular, it doesn't scale well; imagine what this looks like if you have 20 buttons, or 100 menu items (which is not uncommon). It's better (in either toolkit) to create different handlers for each item. Using lambda expressions (which are really not "new features" any more) makes this much easier.

Comment: I know. I just thought he was trying to translate his current `Buttons` to `JavaFX` `Buttons`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is technically possible to integrate JavaFX and Swing.  [Oracle provide a tutorial on this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/fx_swing.htm).  I don't recommend integrating the two unless you really need to (which you probably don't in this case).  Note that the level of integration possible is just embedding Swing Components into JavaFX nodes (or vice versa).  You cannot directly use a Swing listener to take action on a JavaFX button press.

Instead, I recommend that you write your code native to a single library, either JavaFX or Swing.

For your example code. The JavaFX equivalent for handling button actions is:

- [`button.setOnAction(EventHandler<ActionEvent>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#setOnAction-javafx.event.EventHandler-)

---

> How would I set the String for the action command? Is this possible? Or do I have to do it a different way?

You wouldn't, it's not necessary.

I don't code Swing, so I'm not familiar with the Swing ActionEvent.  From looking at your code, your listener seems to be providing a single point for handling multiple action events which originate from different sources, then acting on them.

For JavaFX, just define separate event handlers for each source rather than using switches, then you don't need to pass a string to the action command because it is clear what action is to be taken based upon the context.

For instance:

```
loginButton.setOnAction(event -> { /** handle login **/});
exitButton.setOnAction(event -> { /** handle exit **/});
```

If you have multiple ways to trigger the actions, for instance an exit could be triggered by both a menu item and a button, then you can define a variable for the action handler and reuse that for each instance, for instance:

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> exitHandler = event -> { /** handle exit **/ };
exitButton.setOnAction(exitHandler);
exitMenuItem.setOnAction(exitHandler);
```

Comment: How would I set the String for the action command? Is this possible? Or do I have to do it a different way?

Comment: What if I have more than 200 rows in a TableView? Wouldn't it be inefficient to have an anonimous EventHandler or a functional interface for each button in each custom TableCell of each row?

Comment: TableView is a virtual control, what this means is that it will only render buttons and controls for the portion of the view which is actually visible, not for all rows in the table.  So, whether you have 200 or 200,000 rows in the view, if only 10 are visible at a time, you only have 10 buttons and 10 event handlers.  If all the event handlers for the buttons do similar things, you can define a single event handler (like the exitHandler in the answer) and just set a reference to that common event handler by calling setOnAction for each button, so a single object can service all buttons.